# Building NTP with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, ntp

I am trying to build the latest version of NTP (4.2.8p3 released on 2015/06/29) with OpenSSL support.

I can definitely build NTP but when I try to use ntp-keygen to create a new certificate it tells me that the parameters are unknown.

I use this command line to create a certificate:

```
ntp-keygen -p privatePassword -T -I -i GR1
```

**which gives me :**

```
guillaume@quentin-HP-xw6600-Workstation:~/certifs$ ntp-keygen -p privatePassword -T -I -i GR1
/usr/sbin/ntp-keygen: illegal option -- p
ntp-keygen (ntp) - Create a NTP host key - Ver. 4.2.8p3
Usage:  ntp-keygen [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]...
Try 'ntp-keygen --help' for more information.
```

I have tried to build ntp with different options but I always have the same issue.

Does someone have the same problem ?

I believe this is a problem with this version of NTP but I am not sure... (I have tried to use the dev version but I got the same result). Or maybe the problem is due to my configure options?

My config options :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--datadir=/usr/share \
--sysconfdir=/etc/ntp \
--disable-linuxcaps \
--enable-parse-clocks \
--disable-ipv6 \
--enable-debugging \
--with-crypto \
--with-openssl-libdir=/opt/opt/openssl/lib \
--with-openssl-incdir=/opt/include/openssl \
--enable-autokey \
```

Edit : ntp-keygen --help gives me :

```
guillaume@quentin-HP-xw6600-Workstation:~/certifs$ ntp-keygen --help
ntp-keygen (ntp) - Create a NTP host key - Ver. 4.2.8p3
Usage:  ntp-keygen [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]...
  Flg Arg Option-Name    Description
   -d no  debug-level    Increase debug verbosity level
                - may appear multiple times
   -D Num set-debug-level Set the debug verbosity level
                - may appear multiple times
   -M no  md5key         generate MD5 keys
      opt version        output version information and exit
   -? no  help           display extended usage information and exit
   -! no  more-help      extended usage information passed thru pager
   -> opt save-opts      save the option state to a config file
   -< Str load-opts      load options from a config file
                - disabled as '--no-load-opts'
                - may appear multiple times

Options are specified by doubled hyphens and their name or by a single
hyphen and the flag character.


The following option preset mechanisms are supported:
 - reading file $HOME/.ntprc
 - reading file ./.ntprc
 - examining environment variables named NTP_KEYGEN_*

Please send bug reports to:  <http://bugs.ntp.org, bugs@ntp.org>
```

---

Comment: What does `ntp-keygen --help` say?

Comment: @MadHatter I have edited the post with the output of ntp-keygen --help

Comment: Would you please review your 'code' snippets as they seem to have missing bits. i.e. help does not seem to list the option you specify - configure has a trailing "\" which would suggest another line thereafter at least.  FWIW I ran the command on `ntp-keygen (ntp) - Create a NTP host key - Ver. 4.2.6p5` and it ran fine: `Built against OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012, using version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb Generating new cert file and link
ntpkey_cert_hostname->ntpkey_RSA-MD5cert_hostname.1234831161`

Comment: When I run the command on ntp-keygen I have the same output as you... when I use NTP version 4.2.6. 

The problem comes up when I try to use the latest version of NTP (4.2.8).

For the "\" at the end of the configure, you are right, thanks for that.
What do you mean by _"Would you please review your 'code' snippets as they seem to have missing bits"_ ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: For example in your output of the help, where is the text the details what the -T -I -i options do?  That is what I mean.  You don't get the same output as me @GuillaumeB - or yours would be working.

Comment: OK but I copied and pasted exactly what I saw on the screen. As you can see, there is a huge difference between your output (or mine with NTP version 4.2.6) and mine using version 4.2.8. It is like ntp-keygen has not been built correctly.